# Python Code Optimisation

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Recently I found a puzzle that required me to list all cyclic primes below a number.
In this context cyclic means that if we rotate the digits it is still prime:
eg.
1193 is prime
1931 is prime
9311 is prime
3119 is prime

This is the code I origanly wrote:

```
a=[]
upto=1000000

for x in range(upto):
    a.append([x,0])

print('generated table')

a[1][1]=1
a[0][1]=1

for n in range(2,int(math.sqrt(upto))):
    for k in range(2,(int(upto/n)+2)):
        try:
            a[n*k][1]=1
        except IndexError:
            pass
print('sive complete')

p=[]
for e in a:
    if (e[1]==0):
        p.append(e[0])
print('primes generated')

s=[]
for e in p:
    pr=True
    w=str(e)
    if all(c not in w for c in ['2','4','6','8','5','0']):
        for x in (w[i:]+w[:i] for i in range(len(w))):
            if int(x) not in p:
                pr=False
        if pr==True:
            s.append(e)
            print('found',e)
print(s)
```

It was fairly slow! (about 12s) I know, the prime generation isn't perfect but, the final bit is the slowest. I knew that this process for upto=10e6 can be done in under a second, so after some research I removed any string manipulations in favor of this function:

```
def rotate(n):
    prev=[]
    for l in range(6,0,-1):
        if(n<10**l):
            length=l
    while(n not in prev):
        prev.append(n)
        n=(n // 10) + (n % 10) * 10**(length-1)
        yield n
```

I also removed the 5,0,2,4,6,8 testing as I didn't know how to implement it. The result? It runs even slower! (over ten minutes, I guess the 5,0,2,4,6,8 testing was a good idea)

I tried using time.time() but I didn't find anything terribly inefficient (in the first code). How is it possible to improve this code? Are there any bad practices I'm currently using?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, eliminating the even digits and 5 is certainly of value, as it will remove the vast majority of the numbers you need to test. Any 2+ digit cyclic prime must consist only of some subset of [1, 3, 7, 9]. I would think you might be able to brute-force that for reasonable lengths - for an N-digit solution, there are a max of 4^N possibilities (less with various symmetries), and 4^N < 10^N for any positive N...

Comment: How would it be possible for me to migrate it over there? The amount of coding SEs is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some optimized code:

```
import math

upto = 1000000

a = [True] * upto
p = []

for n in xrange(2,upto):
    if a[n]:
        p.append(n)
        for k in xrange(2,(upto+n-1)//n):
            a[k*n] = False

print('primes generated')

s = []
p = set(p)
for e in p:
    pr=True
    w=str(e)
    if all(c not in w for c in ['2','4','6','8','5','0']):
        for x in (w[i:]+w[:i] for i in range(len(w))):
            if int(x) not in p:
                pr=False
                break
        if pr:
            s.append(e)

print(s)
```

most important optimizations:

1. simplified the sieve code
2. converted the list of primes into a set. This makes the test `x in p` be logaritmic instead of linear
3. added a break statement when found a non prime rotation

**added** cleaner (but equivalent) code:

```
import math

upto=1000000

sieve = [True] * upto
primes = set()

for n in xrange(2,upto):
    if sieve[n]:
        primes.add(n)
        for k in xrange(2,(upto+n-1)//n):
            sieve[k*n] = False

def good(e):
    w = str(e)
    for c in w:
        if c not in '1379':
            return False
    for i in xrange(1,len(w)):
        x = int(w[i:]+w[:i])
        if x not in primes:
            return False
    return True

print filter(good,primes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cut down on the time required for the first test by doing a set comparison instead of doing the full iteration each time like so:

```
flags = set('246850')
if not set(str(e)).intersection(flags):
    # etc...
```

Which not only scales logarithmically, but also lets you pick up another factor of two on this step. You can even speed this up further and make it a little more elegant by transitioning it over to a generator that you can then use to do the final check like so:

```
flags = set('246850')
primes = set(p)
easy_checks = (str(prime) for prime in primes if not set(str(prime)).intersection(flags))
```

Finally you can rewrite that final bit to get rid of all the appending and whatnot, which tends to be super slow like so:

```
test = lambda number: any((int(number[i:]+number[:i]) in primes for i in xrange(len(number))))
final = [number for number in easy_checks if test(number)]
```

Comment: I tried your code to find primes, but it does not work. It gives all numbers.

Comment: For some reason your sieve doesn't work as expected. It claims 4 is prime (primes[2]=4)

Comment: @Michal Oh, fascinating. It looks like python has a weird issue with recursive generators so that doesn't work like it would elsewhere. Removing that portion, but the rest is still valid.

Comment: @Michal It works for me: 4 not in primes